# Looking for a quick way to speed up my code

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, optimization, pandas

I am looking for a way to speed up my code. I managed to speed up most parts of my code, reducing runtime to about 10 hours, but it's still not fast enough and since I'm running out of time I'm looking for a quick way to optimize my code.

**An example:**

```
text = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dir,"text.csv"),chunksize = 5000)
new_text = [np.array(chunk)[:,2] for chunk in text]
new_text = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(new_text))
```

In the code above I read in about 6 million rows of text documents in chunks and flatten them. This code takes about 3-4 hours to execute. This is the main bottleneck of my program. **edit**: I realized that I wasn't very clear on what the main issue was, **The flattening is the part which takes the most amount of time.**

Also this part of my program takes a long time:

```
    train_dict = dict(izip(text,labels))
    result = [train_dict[test[sample]] if test[sample] in train_dict else predictions[sample] for sample in xrange(len(predictions))]
```

The code above first zips the text documents with their corresponding labels (This a machine learning task, with the train_dict being the training set). Earlier in the program I generated predictions on a test set. There are duplicates between my train and test set so I need to find those duplicates. Therefore, I need to iterate over my test set row by row (2 million rows in total), when I find a duplicate I actually don't want to use the predicted label, but the label from the duplicate in the train_dict. I assign the result of this iteration to the variable result in the above code.

I heard there are various libraries in python that could speed up parts of your code, but I don't know which of those could do the job and right know I do not have the time to investigate this, that is why I need someone to point me in the right direction. Is there a way with which I could speed the code snippets above up?

**edit2**

I have investigated again. And it is definitely a memory issue. I tried to read the file in a row by row manner and after a while the speed declined dramatically, furthermore my ram usage is nearly 100%, and python's disk usage increased sharply. How can I  decrease the memory footprint? Or should I find a way to make sure that I don't hold everything into memory?

**edit3**
As memory is the main issue of my problems I'll give an outline of a part of my program. I have dropped the predictions for the time being, which reduced the complexity of my program significantly, instead I insert a standard sample for every non duplicate in my test set.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import os

train = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dir,"Train.csv"),chunksize = 5000)
train_2 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dir,"Train.csv"),chunksize = 5000)
test = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dir,"Test.csv"), chunksize = 80000)
sample = list(np.array(pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dir,"Samples.csv"))[:,2]))#this file is only 70mb
sample = sample[1]
test_set = [np.array(chunk)[:,2] for chunk in test]
test_set = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(test_set))

train_set = [np.array(chunk)[:,2] for chunk in train]
train_set = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(train_set))
labels = [np.array(chunk)[:,3] for chunk in train_2]
labels = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(labels))

"""zipping train and labels"""
train_dict = dict(izip(train,labels))
"""finding duplicates"""
results = [train_dict[test[item]] if test[item] in train_dict else sample for item in xrange(len(test))]
```

Although this isn't my entire program, this is the part of my code that needs optimization. As you can see I am only using three important modules in this part, pandas, numpy and itertools. The memory issues arise when flattening train_set and test_set. The only thing I am doing is reading in the files, getting the necessary parts zipping the train documents with the corresponding labels in a dictionary. And then search for duplicates.

**edit 4**
As requested I'll give an explanation of my data sets. My Train.csv contains 4 columns. The first columns contain ID's for every sample, the second column contains titles and the third column contains text body samples(varying from 100-700 words). The fourth column contains category labels. Test.csv contains only the ID's and text bodies and titles. The columns are separated by commas.

Comment: What is the size (in MB) of text.csv?

Comment: The size of text.csv is almost 7000 MB.

Comment: `numpy` can read CSV files and many parts of `numpy` are heavily optimized (though I'm not sure about its CSV reader).  Also: is the device on which the 7000MB file is stored a "fast" device?  Can you put it on a ramdisk in order to isolate the problem better?

Comment: I was thinking of a RAMdisk myself, to try and localise the problems :-) Though at 100MB/s (which most modern disks can do), that's only 70 seconds of I/O, so there's probably little to be gained from optimising this... may be worth a try though.

Comment: I just store it on my HDD. I do have an SSD (about 25  gigs) would that be feasible?

Comment: Note that your peak memory usage is twice the necessary number during reading because the first new_text assignment gets everything in col 2 and then the next new_text line does the same.  Something like `new_text = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(chunk.iloc[:,2] for chunk in text))` should improve this.  @BrianCain: numpy's csv reading is pretty poor, actually -- a lot of it's done in pure Python.  But it shouldn't take hours to do the flattening, so if that's a bottleneck (presumably due to storing all the elements in memory at once), do that in a simple csv loop instead first.

Comment: The flattening is indeed the main problem. I should edit my post to emphasize that.

Comment: We may need to distinguish between flattening in the sense of removing everything except the second column (which can be done once, out-of-core, and the results stored in a new file) and *reading* the whole second column (which if you need to get into swap, may be unavoidably slow).  That section of the code does both.  What is `sum(map(len, new_text))`, i.e. the total size of the strings you need to keep in memory?

Comment: I have no precise calculations for that, but it lies between 5 and 6 gigs for that specific column. (I have 8 gigs of ram).

Comment: Are you CPU-bound during the flattening?  If so, try using `multiprocessing` to divide up the work.

Comment: The cpu usage is normal.

Comment: How much ram does your computer have?

Comment: 8 gigabtye. It is definitely my ram that is the bottleneck. Just tested it out. Right know my program is doing nothing, ram usage is nearly 100% and disk usage of python increased sharply

Comment: @Learner: then as you're into swap.  The best bet is to modify your algorithm so it doesn't need to store everything in memory at once.  Unfortunately the best ways to do that really depend on exactly what you're doing and what libraries you're using.

Comment: The packages I am using are not that sophisticated, most of the stuff I am using are basic python data structures, combined with reading the files in with pandas and some numpy array conversions. I'll add an edit in which I can give a short outline.

Comment: The list(np.array... bit is not going to be performant, use a list comprehension. Also `for item in xrange(len(test))` should be `for item in test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please post a dummy sample data set of a half dozen rows or so?

I can't quite see what your code is doing and I'm not a Pandas expert, but I think we can greatly speed up this code.  It reads all the data into memory and then keeps re-copying the data to various places.

By writing "lazy" code we should be able to avoid all the re-copying.  The ideal would be to read one line, transform it as we want, and store it into its final destination.  Also this code uses indexing when it should be just iterating over values; we can pick up some speed there too.

Is the code you posted your actual code, or something you made just to post here?  It appears to contain some mistakes so I am not sure what it actually does.  In particular, `train` and `labels` would appear to contain identical data.

I'll check back and see if you have posted sample data.  If so I can probably write "lazy" code for you that will have less re-copying of data and will be faster.

EDIT: Based on your new information, here's my dummy data:

```
id,title,body,category_labels
0,greeting,hello,noun
1,affirm,yes,verb
2,deny,no,verb
```

Here is the code that reads the above:

```
def get_train_data(training_file):
    with open(training_file, "rt") as f:
        next(f)  # throw away "headers" in first line
        for line in f:
            lst = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
            # lst contains: id,title,body,category_labels
            yield (lst[1],lst[2])

train_dict = dict(get_train_data("data.csv"))
```

And here is a faster way to build `results`:

```
results = [train_dict.get(x, sample) for x in test]
```

Instead of repeatedly indexing `test` to find the next item, we just iterate over the values in test.  The `dict.get()` method handles the `if x in train_dict` test we need.

Comment: Thank you very much. I made I typo when defining train and labels I'll edit that too. I'll provide and dummy sample set.

Comment: One question. The text samples in the data set are quite large. Do you actually need them or would an explanation of the datasets be suffice?

Comment: I just need to understand what your program is doing.  "toy" data with the same shape would work just fine.  For example, if your data was the entire contents of a book, you could just put a string like "entire contents of a book goes here" and that's fine.

Comment: Ok, I'll fetch that for you then.

Comment: My train data contains four columns, see edit for explanation.

Comment: This is exactly how I modified your first solution. Anyway thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Cython](http://cython.org/). It supports numpy and can give you a nice speedup.
Here is an introduction and explanation of what needs to be done
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iw9-GckD-gQ

Answer (score 0):

If the order of your rows is not important you can use sets to find elements that are in train set but not in test set (intersection trainset & testset) and add them first to your "result" and after that use set difference (testset-trainset) to add elements that are in your test set but not in the train set. This will allow to save on checking if sample is in trainset.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately order is important.